# Emacs package-install inserting extra dash?

Tags: emacs, package, package-managers

I'm trying to have all of my dependencies install automatically for a new Emacs install. When I put the snippet below in my .emacs I keep getting: `` Package `smex-' is unavailable. ``

I was wondering if this is expected functionality? The Emacs starter-kit did something similar which I remember working before. Using Emacs 24.3.

```
(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))

(defvar my-packages
  '(smex))

(dolist (p my-packages)
  (let ((s (symbol-name p)))
    (when (not (package-installed-p s))
      (package-install s))))
```

---

EDIT

Apparently this was caused by a bug or something. I was able to get it to work now in latest Emacs 24.3.1. Apparently they've also changed it so that package names should be symbols.

```
(package-initialize)

(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))

(defvar my-packages
  '(list of packages))

(dolist (p my-packages)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
    (package-install p)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `package-compute-transaction`:

```el
(error "Package `%s-%s' is unavailable"
       (symbol-name next-pkg)
       (package-version-join next-version))
```

Comment: Well this is what is shooting out the error. I've been looking through package.el, I'll see if I can figure out why it's happening.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue when I was using

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

*after* calling `(package-initialize)`. If I execute

```
(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
                         ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
```

before `(package-initialize)`, then the automated installation logic is able to install missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question: Emacs does not actually insert an extra dash, it is merely a badly formatted error message on older Emacs versions. Ignore the dash.

What was happening is that when Emacs does not find a package `foo` of a version `1.2.3`, it would try to print a message saying `` Package `foo-1.2.3' is unavailable ``. But absence of a version string *(which is okay per se)* was making it print an empty string, so you'd see a message `` Package `foo-' is unavailable `` instead. This problem [was fixed in commit 3e349ee1198c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=3e349ee1198c).

So the bottom line is, on older Emacs versions that still have such print just ignore the dash. All the message `` Package `smex-' is unavailable `` says is it didn't find `smex` for whatever reason.