# Emacs's package-install inserts an extra dash at the end of the package

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've been trying to switch to Emacs again after a few years dabbling with other editors, but whenever I setup MELPA and try to install packages from my .init.el, I get this error.

Basically, package-compute-transaction seems to add a dash at the end of the package names, impeding it to be found in the repository. Installing the packages manually with M-x package-install does work normally.

My init.el (barebones at the moment):

```
;; init.el -- Emacs config

;; MELPA setup and initial packages
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

(package-initialize)

(defvar package-list
  '(better-defaults 
    material-theme))

(dolist (p package-list)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
         (package-install p)))
;; Basic defaults

(setq inhibit-startup-message t) ;; Hide startup mesage
(load-theme 'material t) ;; Load theme: Material
(global-linum-mode t) ;; Line numbers
```

And the error I get running Emacs with --debug-init:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Package ‘better-defaults-’ is unavailable")
  signal(error ("Package ‘better-defaults-’ is unavailable"))
  error("Package `%s-%s' is unavailable" better-defaults "")
  package-compute-transaction(nil ((better-defaults)))
  package-install(better-defaults)
  (progn (package-install p))
  (if (not (package-installed-p p)) (progn (package-install p)))
  (while --dolist-tail-- (setq p (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (not (package-installed-p p)) (progn (package-install p))) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))
  (let ((--dolist-tail-- myPackages) p) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq p (car --dolist-tail--)) (if (not (package-installed-p p)) (progn (package-install p))) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--))))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "c:/Users/Nelthorim/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 830
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/Nelthorim/.emacs.d/init.el" "c:/Users/Nelthorim/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("c:/Users/Nelthorim/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\266
```

This error (same one exactly) happens in both with my Windows desktop and my Linux laptop, with both Emacs 24.5 and 25.0 in both setups.

I found an old SO answer, marked as solved, for a similar problem. But the "solutions" given there don't work.

EDIT: made some changes to my init.el, but no difference in results.

Comment: Have you tried to quote around  the packages in `package-list` like: `(defvar package-list
  '("better-defaults" 
    "material-theme"))`

Comment: Also could you add the question which you reffered too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802757/emacs-package-install-inserting-extra-dash is the old question. I'll try the quotes thing now.

Comment: Adding quotes doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do the packages that you want appear when you run `M-x` `package-list-packages`

Comment: Yes, and I can install them manually with `M-x` `package-install<RET>`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with inserting a dash.  The format of the error message is simply `%s-%s` with the first insert being `better-defaults` and the second insert being an empty string `""`.

Comment: The doc-string for `package-install` states:  "*PKG can be a package-desc or a symbol naming one of the available packages in an archive in ‘package-archives’.*"  Perhaps `better-defaults` is *not* "*one of the available packages in an archive in ‘package-archives’*" and a **symbol** will *not* suffice.  So, consider trying to use a string instead:  `(defvar package-list '("better-defaults" "material-theme"))` and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: That was the first suggestion from @JulesTamagnan, and as stated, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a "typo" was the cause of this error.

Changed:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
     '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

for:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
     '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

Solved the issue.